# Java Spring + Thymeleaf:Problem arranging dual dynamic generated flexboxes in html

Tags: html, css, spring, flexbox, thymeleaf

so i am creating a webapp with Java Spring and thymeleaf.if you look at the photo i have added , on that page all the black arrows indicates what the page does.Basically clicking on "Add FLoor" it adds a big black bordered square like panel.And clicking on "Add Room" it adds a numerotated Room indicated by the red bordered square.

Everything with green in the photo is what i want to do.So basically i want the rooms to be inline with the floor level(indicated in the photo by "Floor 1" and i want all the rooms to be inline with each other indefinetely(so user can scroll left/right), not to go on a different row after room 9.(indicated on Floor 0 green arrow)

this is the photo:
[image]

this is my thymeleaf code:

```
 <section>

        <div id="cool">
            <h1>Add floor</h1>
            <form th:action="@{/addFloor}" method="post">
                <input type="Submit" value="Add Floor">
            </form>
        </div>
        <br>
        <!--LISTS THE FLOORS -->
        <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(allFloors)}">
            <div class="main-floors" th:each="floor : ${allFloors}">
                    <ul>
                        <li th:text="'Floor ' + ${floor.level}"></li>
                        <li>
                            <form th:action="@{/addRoom}" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" th:value="${floor.id}" name="floorId">
                                <input type="Submit" value="Add Room">
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <!-- LISTS THE ROOMS -->
                <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(floor.rooms)}">
                    <div class="rooms" th:each="room : ${floor.rooms}">
                        <ul>
                            <li th:text="${room.name}"></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        

    </section>
```

and this is my current css

```
.main-floors {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    border: 5px solid black;
}

.rooms {
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
border: 5px solid red;
}

ul {
list-style:none;
}
```

i have tried different divs nesting , and switching between flex,inline-block and block for the rooms class but nothing seems to work, the rooms remain in theyr position instead of going inline with the floor level.I do not want to fix it with float right since that takes the element out of flow.
Any help with these 2 problems would be greatly appreciated !